# Need help installing wifi drivers (ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a cudy WU650 usb wifi adapter and im trying to figure out how to install drivers for it, i downloaded linux drivers from their website but they came in a tar.gz file format and im not sure how i should go about it

here are the files inside the archive [tar.gz archive files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06dnB.png)

Comment: You didn't provide your OS/release details (this makes a huge difference, as drivers for each brand/model card aren't installed usually, Linux relies on the chipset instead and the kernel (OS/release) and chipset details matter.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide (device recognition and operation bit is where you'll need to start; it'll let you use search engines or provide us with required details so we can help)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: The duplicate link is based on a guess (based on picture you provided bcm43xx) because you've not provided chipset details which allow specific help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.